# Branching ratio for a bound state

Tags: particle-physics, kinematics, large-hadron-collider

Consider the meson $\Upsilon(10860)$. It decays into $B\bar{B}$, $B\bar{B}^*+cc$ and $B^*\bar{B}^*$. The mass of $B$ is $5.28 ~\textrm{ GeV}$ and mass of $B^*$ is $5.33~\textrm{ GeV}$. The branching ratios for these decays as given in Particle data Group are 
$$ \Gamma( B^*\bar{B}^*)> \Gamma(B\bar{B}^*+cc)\gg\Gamma(B\bar{B}). $$
I want to understand this relation between masses and the branching ratios of the decay products. Please explain.

I think,
Formula of two body decays can not be used as the parent particle is a bound state of $b$ and $\bar{b}$.

Comment: Your middle decay is supposed to be $B^* \bar{B}$ +cc., as @dmckee suggests. You misrepresented the numbers of the masses: they are 5.28 and 5.33, respectively. You omitted the $J^P$ values, $0^-$, $1^-$, respectively, and $1^-$ for the isosinglet bound state. What would you find assuming the *Y* to be a bound state of the decay mesons, and accounting for the angular momentum/spin values?

Comment: @CosmasZachos The numbers are not very different. I want to imply that decay to heavier decay state has more probability. Please explain.

Comment: That was my point about your unwarranted implication, too: you expect 50 MeV differences in ~200 such available energy to dominate, by dint of phase space alone, modes with very different spin signatures in a 5S decay? In any case, which part of table 1 of [Simonov & Veselov](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0370269308014639) do you actually disagree with?

Comment: @CosmasZachos What does the number 200 here refer to?

Comment: In MeV, the smallest available energy, 10860-2x5325~210, very crudely. [See this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/253757441_Measurement_of_Upsilon5S_decays_to_B0_and_B_mesons).

Comment: @CosmasZachos Okay.Thank you. I read the paper but honestly I didnt follow more than 20 %. What I understood is, looking at phase space only, the observed pattern should not be correct. Its because of isospin factor that we observe these decay widths. Please help me here.

Comment: Well, yes and no: Isospin dictates accurately the ratios of charged to neutral B decays, and it is a good symmetry for the high energy scales involved. The big picture is in this [Brambilla et al review](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1140/epjc/s10052-010-1534-9), and the theoretical estimates of Simonov & Veselov I mentioned. It appears like a complex confluence of angular momentum, spin, isospin, and, lastly, mass factors. The only point made is that the usual "everything else being equal"  condition  used in guestimating BR rations on the basis of   just phase space fails.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Thank you. The information and sources were really helpful. If you want you can put it as answer.